# ERROR: flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting a really strange error in Android Studio console and I cannot seem to find the root cause.
The error points to a package called `location` but I don't have such import in my project:

- I searched all project files/folders, including build and gradle folders, no reference to this word/package
- I searched the flutter folder, no such reference

Is it possible that this package is somehow implicitly imported? Where should I look at?

```
[+1346 ms] E/flutter (22947): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
[        ] E/flutter (22947): #0      _HomeState.localPushNotification (package:location/src/Screen.dart:272)
[        ] E/flutter (22947): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this error caused by passing in Null where you declared a String. You should look at the data you defined instead of the package. I solved the same problem before.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Yes, I am passing a null instead of String but how do I find where? There is no such package and no such line 272 in my Screen.dart page.